# How to make TypeScript complain about string concatenation with other type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

Why even in strict mode TypeScript is not complaining about this

```js
function test(firstName: string, lastName?: string): string {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}

test('John');
```

Nor about this

```js
const str: string = '';
const num: object = {};

const result: string = str + num;
```

I don't remember cases when I would want to get and print on the screen '*John undefined*' or '*[object Object]*'.
Is the whole point of type checking is supposed to be catching such errors? (Flow does it)

Comment: Relevant TypeScript GitHub Issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30239

Answer (score 3):

As MartinJohns said [on a github issue regarding this topic](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42983#issuecomment-786628074)

> I think this would belong more to the realm of linters. This is not
> really a type error, it's just undesired behavior.
>
> [no-base-to-string](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-base-to-string.md)
>
> [restrict-plus-operands](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/restrict-plus-operands.md)
>
> [restrict-template-expressions](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/restrict-template-expressions.md)
>
> [no-implicit-coercion](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-implicit-coercion)

Answer (score 0):

Create a type-safe variadic function to do concatenation for you.

```
concat(...strings: string[]): string {
  var concatenated = "";
  for (var i = 0; i <  strings.length; i++) {
    concatenated += strings[i];
  }
  return concatenated;
};
```

Now when you concatenate, use your function:

```
const str: string = '';
const num: object = {};

const result: string = concat(str, num); // throws error
```

[Example here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20str%3A%20string%20%3D%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20num%3A%20object%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20result%3A%20string%20%3D%20this.concat(this.str%2C%20this.num)%3B%20%2F%2F%20throws%20error%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20concat(...strings%3A%20string%5B%5D)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20concatenated%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(var%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20%20strings.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20concatenated%20%2B%3D%20strings%5Bi%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20concatenated%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Answer (score 0):

In the context of the **+ operator**, you can't, because it's designed to be able to support mixed types, for example in the expression `"Count: " + a.length()`.

The conversion of objects to strings can be implied (in + concatenation) and controlled.   In modern JavaScript this might be demonstrated as follows:

```js
let o = {};
o.toString = ()=> "two"
alert("one" + " " + o); // Displays "one two"
```

So there isn't really a reason to reject the second example just based on types.

As to the first example, conversion from `unknown` and `null` to string are implied and defined in abstract ToString() operation, though I'm not sure it's changeable, it seems [well defined.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-tostring)   Now, it certainly might be reason to flag with a tool like **tslint**, but it remains a valid operation in ECMAScript.

Comment: But plenty of things that are valid ECMAScript are invalid in TS. In fact, that's arguably the entire point of TS.

Comment: Saying "invalid in TS" seems too strong.  By definition, typescript is a superset of javascript.   Type-based "error" messages are really just warnings and don't (without specific options enabled) prevent code generation.   In the context of string concatenation (which Typescript can/must recognize), implicit type conversion to strings seems appropriate to allow.

Comment: In practice, concatenation is a commonly used idiom for conversion to string.   `number + ""` is always of type string.

Comment: OP is asking for "complaining" - aka errors. Just because it works in ES doesn't mean TS has to support it error-free. e.g. `let x = 4; x = "a"` is valid ES which gives a TS error.

Answer (score -3):

Because it is valid to concatenate strings and undefined values. Same issue for your second example. In JavaScript, your can `'' + {}` (would not be of much use though, typically).

Strict typing prevents unsafe access like `lastName.length` in your example.

Comment: Right, it's valid in js, but in 99% of the cases it's invalid for application. And flow catches that: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoKBXAdgYwC4CWcWYeApgM54AUUBATlQHICGAtmQFxhX0FYBzADRgYLZuzIB+br34CAlLLx9BYAN6ow2sPTJ4M9EnUZ5WHMAGowAIltXR4s5IDcqAL6pU5KtQDkAFJwABZYfgpuQA and https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAxnAdgZwC5j4BOAXIXkQJZYDmYAvGAORMDcG2+YWArgLYMwAbwC+7DrgJEApjh4w8ZYtTqNiYANTd+rIA