# Is it possible to prevent automatic cast to string with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, casting, type-safety

The following code type-checks:

```js
type Point = {x: number, y: number};
const p: Point = ...get a point...;
const r = p + " is too far";
```

Is there a way to prevent this, by making this a compile-time error (via a TypeScript option, perhaps)?
The problem is that, at runtime, `r` will be `"[object Object] is too far"`, which is almost always unintended (unless `p` had a `toString()` method).

Comment: I don't believe so. For what it's worth, it's perfectly legal to concatenate strings and non strings, even if it's usually a bad idea. Meaning that it should never generate a runtime error.

Comment: The same question from a few years ago (2018) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095599/how-to-make-typescript-complain-about-string-concatenation-with-other-type

Comment: This is a case where you could check whether typeof p === 'string'

Comment: @joshstrike I could but I'd prefer to have this detected at compile-time rather than at runtime.